# How do I filter pivot table rows by values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

This seems like a simple question but there doesn't seem to be an answer online. I had a read through this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/filter-data-in-a-pivottable-HA102840040.aspx but it doesn't seem to be much help.

Suppose I have a pivot table in which one of the count is a count of the number of times each value from another column appears in the data. Now I want to display only rows where the count is, say, larger than 1.

How do I do this?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Perhaps you could reword it and use some pictures so it's more clear?

Comment: Your link tells you how to do what you are looking for. Just select `Value Filters` and enter greater than `1`.

Comment: @guitarthrower you're right, I misread.

Comment: added as an answer. If you mark as complete, it may help others with the same questions. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link tells you how to do what you are looking for. Just select `Value Filters` and enter greater than `1`.